# CPU vulnerabilities and web JavaScript

Tags: linux, cpu, javascript, web, vulnerabilities

(using Linux desktop)

I am paranoid about Spectre/Meltdown/similar and the fact that JavaScript delivered through web browser can read whatever is in my RAM.

I have disabled all JS and when I enable it selectively for one website only, I:

- close all open programs
- clear clipboard
- always browse in incognito mode with one tab only
- keep the site open as short as possible

Is that "simulation of single tasking" meaningful or a waste of time?

How do you approach the issue?

Comment: These attacks require _very_ precise timing. It has since been removed from browsers.

Comment: Spectre/Meltdown mitigation’s have been released for nearly every version of Windows, MacOS, Android, iOS, and Linux kernel.  Are you sure your system is even vulnerable?

Comment: But mitigations are *not* fixes and not all mitigations exist for all CPUs. Older ones are only partially mitigated. On one of my old 32-bit laptops `grep . /sys/devices/system/cpu/vulnerabilities/*` shows almost everything is *not* mitigated. Another system (also old but 64 bit) is partially mitigated only. Older Androids will never be updated either. So the question remains.

Comment: @stackerist - If a system has received a mitigation, to those specific vulnerabilities, it means the vulnerability cannot be exploited on those systems. If you have systems that cannot be protected against Spectre/Meltdown, and run an OS and/or hardware, that makes them vulnerable it's time to take them offline.

Comment: @Ramhound - That's somewhat off-topic but: I am lucky to have systems which are *without* Intel ME. New systems may be better mitigated but Intel ME itself is a much bigger security backdoor. So you see - to take down a system which doesn't have it at all in order to replace it with "latest greatest" is not quite that simple. The newer the hardware, the more the hardware (+firmware) backdoors. RISC-V may be the solution but it has still not made it to desktop.

Answer (score 3):

Likely a waste of time. You still have programs running, even if they don't show desktop windows. And if you have lots of RAM there are likely remnants of the closed programs in it (and file buffers....). The "incognito mode with one tab" isn't buying you much for this... So, better run the whole browser on distinct hardware (cheap notebook, Rpi)

These attacks are difficult, and therefore expensive. They give access to some RAM, but getting an interesting tidbit in 8GB of RAM takes time and devotion. Attackers wouldn't be interested in the RAM contents of some random individual and would search more profitable targets. So unless you have industrial, financial or national secrets on your system (but if it were the case, there would be an IT security officer telling what to do) you won't be the target of such attacks.

Comment: I would say: everyone who has stored credentials has "financial" (and other, personally significant for one's life) secrets. Of course I understand there are background processes etc. but that doesn't mean they expose security information to RAM (neither it means the opposite, generally speaking). Also the argument about the "random individual" doesn't make much sense. Any well known privacy-abusing big tech that hosts a huge deal of JS for millions of sites can automate this. So it is no longer an individually targeted attack. We can suppose probability but it is still a supposition.

Comment: “Big tech“ is most certainly not hacking your computer. I’m sorry, but that’s just preposterous. They are selling all the data they can get their hands on, yes. But hacking is illegal, plain and simple. // Also, it appears you are grossly overestimating what these attacks can do.

Comment: @DanielB, so your non-preposterous answer is that "hacking is impossible/unlikely because it is illegal"? I guess then J. Assange who proved that attacks get automated more and more is preposterous too, so is Snowden. And no - I am not overestimating. I am reading the whitepapers which demonstrate that it is possible to read the RAM.

Comment: Yes, you can ready RAM. No, you don’t know where to read. No, it’s not fast. No, big tech will not use it. You can’t just go “OK I’ll attack this PC with Meltdown” and poof you have its memory contents. This is a very complex attack that relies on precise timing and whatnot. It requires precise decision-making to get to the secret to extract. It is not feasible for blanket attacks.

Comment: Now you are saying "it is impossible/unlikely because it is too difficult to exploit". If it is so difficult - why did they create the mitigations?

Comment: @stackerist - Hypervisors, the exploits you mentioned specifically, made VMs extremely vulnerable.

Comment: Difficult doesn't mean impossible. As said above it's a matter of cost v.s. benefit for hackers, or of cost v.s. consequences for potential victims. Attacking a small fry like you is not worth it. But when you are a big organization and run VMs in the cloud, you could end up with one of your VMs running on the same hardware than another VM set up by hackers and you want to make sure that in that case they cannot peek into your RAM.